# which rxjs operators to use in which order in auto save scenario

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to autosave a form with RxJS in Angular.
The form will emit an event when it is changed

This is the scenario:

1. When the form output has changed, but does not change again within the next 10 seconds, it should emit a save event.
2. Only If the form keeps changing more than once per 10 seconds, for at least 30 seconds, it should also emit a save event.

For the first I could use a debounce, but how do I combine it with my second rule?

Comment: Can you please explain second pointer more clearly ?

Comment: Can you share the code what you already have tried and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split your stream into two streams.

```js
const source = fromEvent(document.getElementById("text"), "input");

source
  .pipe(debounceTime(10 * 1000))
  .subscribe(() => console.log("saved after typing!"));

source
  .pipe(
    auditTime(10 * 1000)
  )
  .subscribe(() => console.log("saved while typing!"));
```

In first case, as you wrote in question, using debounceTime value will be emitted 10 seconds after user finished editing form/input. In second case, auditTime every 10 second will check if there is any new value. If there is, then would be emitted value. In callback you can reuse the same function responsible for saving data from form.
You can try it in this demo on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jj3kot?file=index.ts

I just changed time in demo to 1 second so it is easier to check result in console.

**Side note:**

This is plain JS demo. If you develop Angular app you should avoid getting elements with getElementById. Instead of this use direct reference to template: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

**Edit:**

According to OP comment I've changed implementation a little bit. I merged two observables and used distinctUntilChanged operator to avoid emitting the same value twice. Demo in stackblitz is also changed

```js
const afterTyping = source.pipe(debounceTime(1000));

const whileTyping = source.pipe(auditTime(1000));

merge(whileTyping, afterTyping)
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks, one problem: If I load the stackblitz and type one character it will save two times, one from source one and one from source 2. Optimal is one. I think I need to clear the audittime event whenever the debounce time emit? Can I do that?

Comment: Of course it is possible. I've changed implementation in answer and stackblitz

Comment: thanks, tested it, exactly what i need, clear and simple

Answer (score 1):

This one was a little tricky but a proper combination of `debounceTime` and `throttleTime` can solve the problem:

```
const s = new Subject();
s.subscribe();

const saveEvery3sSubject = new Subject();
saveEvery3sSubject.subscribe();

const saveEvery3s$ = saveEvery3sSubject.pipe(
  throttleTime(3000),
  mapTo('saving after 3000 ms'),
  startWith(null)
);


const debounce$ = s.pipe(
  tap(r => {
    saveEvery3sSubject.next(r); // this step starts the 3000ms timer
  }),
  debounceTime(1000),
  startWith(null),
);

// combining them both so the saving will occur on debounce or after 3000ms
const result$ = combineLatest([debounce$, saveEvery3s$]).pipe(
    filter(([d, s]) => s !== null)
)


// first 5 values will be debounced forever because 500 < 1000(debounceTime)
interval(500).pipe(
    take(5)
)
  .subscribe(i => {
    s.next('form changed #' + i);
})

// these values will be emitted correctly one by one
timer(9000, 1100).pipe(
    take(20)
)
  .subscribe(i => {
    s.next('after pause #' + i);
})

result$.subscribe();
```

Using an additional Subject is necessary because you operate two independent time frames:

- debounceTime - while changing the form and emitting the changes
- throttleTime - to make sure that every 30s the form is saved regardless the debounced input (if you are quicker than debounceTime, the values won't me emitted at all!)

After the first formChange enter the stream with debounce, it starts the timer (in my example - 3000ms) meaning that if there are no user input, there will be no necessary emissions.

Also pay attention to `startWith(null)` - this is required for `combineLatest` to emit the first value.

This solution in action:
https://rxviz.com/v/38MZnMZo

Answer (score 0):

I had to use [race](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/race) to make it work as `merge` was simply never triggered. So here's my working solution:

```
race([
  event.pipe(debounceTime(30 * 1000)),
  event.pipe(throttleTime(30 * 1000))
])
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(console.log);
```